# self updating renewal term date

Tags: excel, wcf, loops, date

I am looking to create a fromula that takes a contracts intial end date, and compares it to todays date. If the contracts intial end date is less then todays date then the contract should automatically update the new end date to 1 or 2 years (depending on the contracts auto renewal) past the previous end date.

The formual I created is:

```
=IF($D$9>(IF($D$9>F11,(DATE(2015,7,24)+365*(1)),(F11))),((DATE(2015,7,24)+365*(2))),((DATE(2015,7,24)+365*(1))))
```

$D$9= todays date.

The problem with this formula is I have to manualy enter each DATE( year, month, day) formula per client, and if the clients contract has been renewed more then once the formula doesnt update.

Comment: Could you not put the clients date in another cell and reference that, like you've done for todays date?

Comment: Excel would not recognize the date in a normal date format. It seems to only accept manually entered dates.

Comment: This seems to imply it should work https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Add-or-subtract-dates-b83768f5-f695-4311-98b1-757345f7e926

Comment: You were right I was able to update it without using the "DATE" formula. The problem is it still only runs the logic 1 time. for instance If a contract expried in 2013 it will only compare to todays date and update 1 time. Is there a way to make the formula keep checking itself off the date to ensure the correct answer?
My current formula is : 
=IF($D$9>IF($D$9>F11,(F11+365*(1)),(F11)),(F11+365*2),(F11))

F11 is the end of the contract

Answer (score 0):

"have to manualy enter each DATE( year, month, day) " <-- you can always put year, month, day as a saperate cell, then link it to the formula.

"if the clients contract has been renewed more then once the formula doesnt update" <--- 2 things :

1. with only using non-vba formula, it will update only once.
2. you can always use extra rows/column to indicate/do the extension.. add built a formula around it. Eg. `if( <renewBox1> = 1 , <renewOnce>, <noRenew>)` then `if( <renewBox2> = 1 , <renewOnce_based on previousExtendedDate>, <noRenew>)`

Hope that helps.